# directory_iterator сортировка

Tags: c++, c++17

согласно
 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator

*The iteration order is unspecified, except that each directory entry is visited only once.*

Как правильно пройтись по директории и отсортировать содержимое?

```
std::string html;

for (auto & p : std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(filepath))
{
    std::string current = format("<p><a href=""%s"">%s</a></p>", p.path().filename().c_str(), p.path().filename().c_str());
    html += current;
}
```

Желательно, чтобы это был такой порядок: сначала все папки в алфавитном порядке, потом файлы в алфавитном порядке.

Единственное решение на данный момент - при первом проходе по директории складывать папки в вектор папок, файлы - в вектор файлов, потом сортировать вектор1, вектор2 и собирать обратно в результирующий вектор, но как-то громоздко...

Comment: Ну так поскольку это *входной итератор*, то другого пути как бы и нет...

Comment: Не единственное. Можно складывать не в вектор, а в std::set, тогда сразу будут и отсортированы. :]

Comment: `std::set` содержит уникальные объекты. А файлы в разных папках могут иметь одинаковые имена. Таким образом, часть файлов может исчезнуть.

Comment: Как вариант, при проходе: если элемент папка - добавляем в нужную точку вектора ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843525/how-do-you-insert-the-value-in-a-sorted-vector)), если элемент файл - записываем в дополнительный вектор. После прохода, сортируем вектор 'файлов' в результирующий вектор [так](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy)